# Do we need to hide the prompt

Tags: discussion

As some languages can be used in command prompts(no matter which), some of them return the current directory like this:

```
C:\Foo\Bar>command
```

So here comes my question:

Do we need to hide the prompt in PPCG answers?

Comment: I don't have Windows so I can't test: does the prompt get printed to STDOUT or STDERR?

Comment: @Dennis I think it should be both STDOUT and STDERR. STDOUT when executing an error-free command, STDERR when executing command with error(s)

Comment: Well, you can't mangle actual output and whatever the interpreter produces. If your program outputs to STDOUT, STDOUT should be free from any prompts.

Comment: @Dennis oh ok. maybe you can post an answer for this.

Comment: Since my answer would currently based on an assumption, I'd rather not. I'll let the Batch golfers handle this one.

Comment: @Dennis turns out I found some other things like `bash` shell also displays the prompt, so I changed the question not only batch specific.

Comment: Bash does no such thing when you run the program from a file.

Comment: @Dennis My fault. I thought batch is 90% like batch except the OS and the way it works.